# The PyCharm always search the file from /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/six.pyc

Tags: python, https, pycharm

When I use the PtCharm I find the PyCharm always search the file from `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/six.pyc`. The error is:

```
File /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/jenkins/__init__.py, line 59, in <module>
    from six.moves.http_client import BadStatusLine
ImportError: No module named http_client
```

I have added the `PYTHONPATH` and run the project with python self is OK.

Comment: The path above (/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/six.pyc) sounds like a Mac OS X path to me (if that helps). Any chance your OS is detected wrong or you picked the wrong download (mac vs linux)?

Comment: Or are you running OS X and just ended up on Ask*Ubuntu* by accident?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Which version of django you are using.

Comment: Are you running OS X?

Answer (score 1):

After a bit of googling and filtering those results, i found something interesting about this issue: apparently there seems to be some sort of compatibility error with the module "http_client". Older versions of (in the example i found) Django (up to 3.1.1) have no issue loading/connecting to the module, where newer versions (3.1.2 onward) seem to get the same issue you stated above: "No module named http_client".

The full article (including a way around the issue (using Django)) can be found here: https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/issues/2969

Hope it helps.